# sql exception : The statement has been terminated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running this SQL statement

```
exec sp_executesql
  N'UPDATE dbo.PricingProfileRuleSetCondition
SET    RuleGroup = @p0,
       JoinClause = @p1,
       ColumnName = @p2,
       Operator = @p3,
       Value = @p4,
       RuleSetId = @p5
WHERE  Id = @p6',
N'      @p0 int,
        @p1 nvarchar(4000),
        @p2 nvarchar(4000),
        @p3 nvarchar(4000),
        @p4 nvarchar(4000),
        @p5 bigint,
        @p6 bigint'
,
@p0=0,
@p1=N'And',
@p2=N'DMS.Finance.Entities.PartnerAccountTransactionAmountType.EnglishName',
@p3=N'eq',
@p4=N'dsaf',
@p5=4,
@p6=6
```

and I'm getting

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

help,please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A string you are trying to insert is longer than the max nr of charachters. E.g. like a string with 4001 charachters in a varchar(4000) datatype.

Answer (score 3):

The column definitions for dbo.PricingProfileRuleSetCondition are too short for the data you're entering.

So one of the values of @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4 is too long for the relevant column, despite your declaration of parameters as nvarchar(4000). Personally, I'd match parameter datatype and length to the columns.

Random thought: if you have declared columns as (n)varchar without a length, the length defaults to 1.

Saying that, why use dynamic SQL at all in this case? It would be a simple parameterised update.

Answer (score 2):

One of your columns data type is not big enough for the string you are assigning. You need to increase the data max length or truncate the string.

It's probably ColumnName, which you are trying to assign a string of length 69.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, if you need to safely truncate the data down to a length of 4000, look into the "left" or "right" functions.

Answer (score 0):

try to minimize the length of the entry data
or
maximize the table column length